# input type="hidden" or display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a form that receives about 100 to 150 spams per day from the same person. I need to add a captcha. 
But my question is different.

```
input="hidden"
```

If you open the developer tools, and just change the type to text, voilà, you have the input visible. Same thing with display none.

Is there a way for the hidden type to be invisible in the developer tools? Or this type is just for the people who know nothing about computers and will not do anything malicious anyways?

Comment: Just make a captcha which is validated server side.

Comment: I am doing it, @Tyr

Answer (score 2):

Displaying a web page is done on the client side. The browser (more or less) just interprets what it is receiving from the server.

Even if one particular browser would hide elements, another one might not or the attacker might not even use a browser at all. The only way of reliably not displaying page content in the developer tools is not sending it to the client in the first place.